# AspectJ @Around and @After throwing on same method is not working

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I have two applied @Around and @After throwing annotation on a method. @Around method is doing Authorization, @After throwing is handling the exception when Authorization throws an exception, see the example below:

```java
class AuthClass {

    @Authorize
    @HandleException
    public String isValidUser() {
        return "yes";
    }
}
```

```java
public aspect AuthorizeAdvice {

    declare precedence : HandleExceptionAdvice;

    pointcut authorizeRequest() : execution (@Authorize * *(..));

    Object around() : authorizeRequest() {
        //call method which throws exception
        throw new AppException();
    }
}
```

```java
public aspect HandleExceptionAdvice {

    pointcut handleException() : execution (@HandleException  * *(..));

    after() throwing(AppException e) : handleException() && 
        !within(HandleException) {
        //handle AppException here
    }
}
```

```java
public aspect CachingAspect {

    pointcut cachePut() : execution(@Cacheable * *(..));

    Object around() : cachePut() {
      //do caching stuff
    }
}
```

My question here is, when `AuthorizeAdvice` aspect throws `AppException`, `HandleExceptionAdvice` aspect intercepts the `AppException` and handling the exception perfectly. But the problem started when I added one more aspect `CachingAspect`. `CachingAspect` is not applied to any methods of `AuthClass` but `HandleExceptionAdvice` is not intercepting `AppException` when `AuthorizeAdvice` throws `AppException`.